# Last car coordinates tracking

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-streams-scala

I have a kafka topic, where I'm storing car position data. I need to write a stream which show me only the last 4 coordinates for each car. 
How can I do this in kafka streams?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a windowed aggregation per car with the aggregation result being a list of the last 4 position records. Check out the docs and example how to do a window aggregation in general.

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html
- https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples